# Nexus and Docker Caching error for images with username

Tags: docker, nexus3

I've been using nexus as a docker repository for a while to mitigate flakey internet. However recently, I've hit an issue that seems a bit weird. So, if I run:

`docker pull server:8042/alpine:3.16.2`

it works fine and it all gets cached. However, if I try and run

`docker pull server:8042/sameersbn/gitlab:15.0.3`

I get the following error:

`Error response from daemon: unknown image in /v1.41/images/create?fromImage=server%3A8042%2Fsameersbn%2Fgitlab&tag=15.0.3`

Running a direct pull from docker works fine, but using the cache, any nested tag with a username fails. I'm using engine 20.10.20 if that helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This seems like it's related to your registry server; it doesn't seem like something that will have a generic answer applicable to other users, nor does it seem like the sort of programming-related question that's on-topic for Stack Overflow.  Another site like [devops.se] might be a more appropriate place to ask; make sure you include enough details of your registry setup that others can understand and reproduce it.

Comment: It seems to be related to the changes between docker engine 20.10.16 and 20.10.20. Fortunately I have a machine that I haven't updated which works fine. There seems to be breaking change between the two. I appreciate its more on the DevOps side, but using Nexus as a local repo for personal and caching is very common. It's been the pattern at the last 3 companies I've worked for.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug introduced somewhere between engine 20.10.17 and 20.10.20. Rolling back to an earlier version makes everything work again. I have also reported this to docker, however as I'm not a paid member, I suspect this will go unnoticed.